# MS Access dlookup over two tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

It came out, that I did a mistake while normalizing my database.
After normalizing it again, my problems are gone now.
Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it very much.

The Question below therefore does not need to answered anymore.

==================================================================

I've got a stupid problem in Access and can't go on in my project, I will try to explain it and hope you can help me. Maybe I think to complicated because I haven't worked with Access ever before. Everything can help, let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

I have a `tblForecastList` with a `PlanningCycle` and a `CalendarCategory`.
The `CalendarCategory` isn't relevant.

The `PlanningCycle`-Number (`plcNumber`) looks like this for example:
`201406`, which means 2014 Q3

Based on this number I want to fill the `tblForecastList` with the next 18 Months which is required for the Forecasting-Process. That would look like this (I will use the correct values for the IDRefs instead of the IDs themself because they wouldn't help to explain)

```
fclID    fcl_plcIDRef    fcl_calcIDRef    Month1    Month2    ....    Month18
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12          201406       (not relevant)  2014June  2014July         2015December
```

In a query for the forecastlist I tried to use nested `DLookups` based on the `plcNumber` to get the CalendarID from the table `tblCalendar`, that looked like this but it isn't working.

`DLookUp( [tblCalendar]![calID], "tblCalendar", "cal_calmIDRef = " & DLookUp( [tblCalendarMonths]![calmID], "tblCalendarMonths","calmMonthNo = 06") AND DLookUp( [tblCalendarYears]![calyID], "tblCalendarYears", "calyYear = 2014'))`

*If you have read to this point, you are awesome and if you can help me solving the Problem, you are even more awesome. *

Thank you very much for your time.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want to create a query, based on the data in your other tables, instead of a new table? And if you say you try to create a query for the forecastlist, where do the DLookups come from? I am kind of confused on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming calmMonthNo and calyYear are both text types, you can use this instead:

```
DLookup("[calID]", "tblCalendar", "[calID] = " & _
        "(SELECT tblCalendar.calID " & _
        "FROM (tblCalendar INNER JOIN tblCalendarMonths " & _
        "ON tblCalendar.cal_calmIDRef = tblCalendarMonths.calmID) " & _
        "INNER JOIN tblCalendarYears ON tblCalendar.cal_calyIDRef = tblCalendarYears.calyID " & _
        "WHERE (((tblCalendarMonths.calmMonthNo)='06') AND ((tblCalendarYears.calyYear)='2014')))")
```

You can stuff a real query in your WHERE clause in DLookup if you call it as a subquery.  it's much easier to see what's going on than nested DLookups, imo.  The only thing here is the datatypes of calmMonthNo and calyYear; I am assuming they are text so they have single quotes surrounding the lookup terms.  If they are numeric types, just remove the single quotes.

Comment: Hi again. Came to a point now where I actually needed your code. I copy/pasted it blind into my code and it worked instantly. Thank you very much.